# Can't resolve all parameters + error + for service unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am receiving the following error:..

```
Can't resolve all parameters for Service1: (?, ?).

Service1.ts
export class Service1 {
constructor(protected url: string, protected http: HttpClient) { }
}

Service1.spec.ts
describe('Service1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [Service1],
    });
  });

    it('should be created', () => {
      const service1: Service1 = TestBed.get(Service1);
      expect(service1).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Have mocked inly httpclient module here, If it mocke url:stirng part it will work i think so.So how can i mock and makke the test pass?.

Comment: You are trying to inject a `url` string into the service. Angular can not know which url it is supposed to inject here therefore this should fail both in tests and in the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Angular doesn't know what to inject for `protected url: string`.

Therefore, you need to provide a token for it.

```js
// Service1.ts
export const APP_URL = new InjectionToken('APP_URL');

export class Service1 {
constructor(
  @Inject(APP_URL) protected url: string,
  protected http: HttpClient,
) { }
}
```

```js
// Service1.spec.ts
describe('Service1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        Service1,
        {
          provide: APP_URL,
          useValue: 'mock',
        },
      ],
    });
  });

    it('should be created', () => {
      const service1: Service1 = TestBed.get(Service1);
      expect(service1).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```